# Response.StatusCode is null in nunit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, response

i am writing unit test cases. I am trying to write unit test for this method but showing error. How to unit test this method in mvc3 framework and rhino mock.

```
        public ActionResult UnderConstruction()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
        ErrorModel model = new ErrorModel()
        {
            ErrorMessage = "This page is still under construction; please check back later.",
            Title = "Under Construction"
        };
        return View("Error", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `Response` that is null, not `Response.StatusCode`. You need to mock `HttpContextBase` and `HttpResponseBase`, and then create and assign the controller's `ControllerContext`.

The test will look something like this (sorry if I fudge the Rhino Mock code; I use Moq normally):

```
// arrange
var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();

// stub both Request and Response, for good measure.
httpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(request);
httpContext.Stub(x => x.Response).Return(response);           

var controller = new YourController();

// create and assign the controller context
var context = new ControllerContext(httpContext, 
                  new RouteData(), 
                  controller);
controller.ControllerContext = context;

// act
var actual = controller.UnderConstruction() as ViewResultBase;

// assert
Assert.That(actual, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(controller.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect));
// etc.
```